# UPDATE fails to update attribute in sqlite3 database

Tags: python, sqlite

I created the following table for a webapp I'm building:

```
# create itemListTable
itemListTable = """ CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS itemListCollection (
   itemUUID text PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
   itemName text NOT NULL,
   itemPrice real NOT NULL,
   itemStatus text NOT NULL, 
   itemImgURL text NOT NULL,
   parentProductListUUID text NOT NULL 
); """
```

When I attempt to update the `itemStatus` column in an extant item entry in `itemListCollection`, nothing happens, despite my making sure to commit the changes I am trying to make to the database:

```
def updateItemStatusInDB(itemUUID, statusValue):
   with sqlite3.connect(databaseFile) as conn:
      c = conn.cursor()
      c.execute("UPDATE itemListCollection SET itemStatus = ? WHERE itemUUID = ?", (statusValue, itemUUID, )) 
      conn.commit()  
      c.close()
   return
```

Is there perhaps something wrong in the syntax of my query? The database is populated with entries, and I can successfully retrieve the contents of a row with `"SELECT * FROM itemListCollection WHERE itemUUID=?"`, so I don't get why the above wouldn't work. Note that I'm running these database operations on a flask server.

Answer (score 1):

In a moment of supreme folly, it turns out that the above code was not mistaken -- I had merely messed up the order of arguments when I invoked the `updateItemStatusInDB()` method in my code.